# How to create an entity when another is updating

Tags: api, rest, symfony, api-platform.com

I have two entities, the first is called Registration and is intended to store the user data while a confirmation email is used to activate the account. The second one is called Account and is the actual entity storing the user data that was previously in Registration.

I want this second entity to be created/persisted in the DB only after the user confirms its registration, at that stage the Registration entity will turn its flag `isActive` to true and will transfer the required data to the be persisted Account.

How to do that using the API platform?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way, although I don't know if it is the best approach: using a custom `state processor`.

Say we have two entities: `Registration` and `Account`. `Registration` will store the attempt to create an account while `Account` will store relevant data about the account once it is created. The are not related in any 'declared' way but the second depends on the first.

The logic is here: "How to use a custom state processor to create an entity when another is updating"

```php
#[ApiResource]
#[Patch(
    //...
    processor: ActivateAccount::class
)]
class Registration
{
   //...
}
```

and here is the ActivateAccount class:

```php
class ActivateAccount implements ProcessorInterface
{
    private ProcessorInterface $decorated;
    private EntityManagerInterface $manager;

    public function __construct(
        ProcessorInterface $decorated,
        EntityManagerInterface $manager
    ) {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function process(
        mixed $data,
        Operation $operation,
        array $uriVariables = [],
        array $context = []
    ) {
        if (!$data->isIsActive()) // we only want to create a new account if current registration is inactive
        {
            $account = new Account();
            $account->setEmail($data->getEmail()); // get the email from the registration data
            $account->setPassword($data->getPassword()); // get password from registration data, already hashed
            $this->manager->persist($account); // save the account to DB
            $this->manager->flush();
            $data->setIsActive(true); // update the registration to prevent the attempt to create another caacount with this data
        }
        $this->decorated->process(
            $data,
            $operation,
            $uriVariables,
            $context
        ); // finally process the registration, this really means save the updated entity
    }
}
```

This custom processor needs to be wired in services configuration:

```yaml
services:
  App\State\ActivateAccount:
    bind:
      $decorated: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.state.persist_processor'
```

And the job is done!

Comment: Hey, coming to this ticket after a while, had the same problem but in my case, even without cascade persist it looks like the flush() isn't even necessary in the processor . Regards

Comment: @Guillaume Im almost sure you need to call flush at least onece to effectively execute the transactions

Comment: Yes you're right ! But I felt like in my case without explicite call of flush, the `process` function was doing the job, not sure about this